# ValueError: Tensor Tensor(...) is not an element of this graph. When using global variable keras model

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I'm running a web server using flask and the error comes up when I try to use vgg16, which is the global variable for keras' pre-trained VGG16 model. I have no idea why this error rises or whether it has anything to do with the Tensorflow backend.
Here is my code:

```
vgg16 = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

def getVGG16Prediction(img_path):
    global vgg16

    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)

    pred = vgg16.predict(x)
    return x, sort(decode_predictions(pred, top=3)[0])

@app.route("/uploadMultipleImages", methods=["POST"])
def uploadMultipleImages():
    uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file[]")
    for file in uploaded_files:
        path = os.path.join(STATIC_PATH, file.filename)
        pInput, result = getVGG16Prediction(path)
```

Here is the full error:
[image]

Any comment or suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `avital`'s answer on [this github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2397). Quoting the relevant part here:

> Right after loading or constructing your model, save the TensorFlow graph:
>
> ```
> graph = tf.get_default_graph()
> ```
>
> In the other thread (or perhaps in an asynchronous event handler), do:
>
> ```
> global graph
> with graph.as_default():
>     (... do inference here ...)
> ```

I modified this a bit and stored the graph in my app's config object instead of making it a global.

The [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_default_graph) for `get_default_graph` explains why this is necessary:

> NOTE: The default graph is a property of the current thread. If you create a new thread, and wish to use the default graph in that thread, you must explicitly add a with g.as_default(): in that thread's function.