# Celery task for ML prediction hangs in execution

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, flask, redis, celery

I'm trying to create a web application that receives an input from POST request and provides some ML predictions based on that input.

Since prediction model is quite heavy, I don't want that user waits for calculation to complete. Instead, I delegated heavy computation to Celery task and user can later inspect the result.

I'm using simple Flask application with Celery, Redis and Flower.

My `view.py`:

```
@ns.route('predict/')
class Predict(Resource):
    ...
    def post(self):
        ...
        do_categorize(data)
        return jsonify(success=True)
```

My `tasks.py` file looks something like this:

```
from ai.categorizer import Categorizer
categorizer = Categorizer(
    model_path='category_model.h5',
    tokenizer_path='tokenize.joblib',
    labels_path='labels.joblib'
)


@task()
def do_categorize(data):
    result = categorizer.predict(data)
    print(result)
    # Write result to the DB
    ...
```

My `predict()` method inside `Categorizer` class:

```
def predict(self, value):
    K.set_session(self.sess)
    with self.sess.as_default():
        with self.graph.as_default():
            prediction = self.model.predict(np.asarray([value], dtype='int64'))
            return prediction
```

I'm running Celery like this:

```
celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=DEBUG
```

The problem that I'm having for the last couple of days is that `categorizer.predict(data)` call hangs in the middle of the execution.

I tried to run `categorizer.predict(data)` inside of post method and it works. But if I place it inside Celery tasks it stop working. There is no console log, if I try to debug it it just freezes on `.predict()`.

My questions:

- How can I solve this issue?
- Is there any memory, CPU limit for the worker?
- Are Celery tasks the "right" way to do such heavy computations?
- How can I debug this problem? What am I doing wrong?
- Is it correct to initialize models at the top of the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459205/3355367) I found the answer for my problem:

It turns out that is better for Keras to work with `Threads` pooling instead of default `Process`.

Lucky for me, with Celery 4.4 `Threads` pooling was reintroduced not a long time ago.
You can read more at [Celery 4.4 Changelogs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.4.html#threaded-tasks-pool):

> Threaded Tasks Pool
>
> We reintroduced a threaded task pool using 
>   concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor.
>
> The previous threaded task pool was experimental. In addition it was based on the threadpool package which is obsolete.
>
> You can use the new threaded task pool by setting worker_pool to ‘threads` or by passing –pool threads to the celery worker command.

Now you can use threads instead of processes for pooling.

```
celery worker -A your_application --pool threads --loginfo=INFO
```

If you can not use latest Celery version, you have possibility to use `gevent` package:

```
pip install gevent
celery worker -A your_application --pool gevent --loginfo=INFO
```